# Emgu cv showing webcam stream as flipped image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I implemented a simple application to get video steam form a normal web camera , and show on a windows application using `CAPTURE` class.

The application works and i can see the video on the image box , but the frames in the video is flipped (my left side is shown in right side).

I tried with multiple cameras and the same problem remains.When i connect the same camera in other application such as skype, there is no flip problem.

Is it a normal behaviour in `capture` class?
How can solve this problem?

I followed [this](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/entries/emgu-cv-c/level-1---lets-make-a-camera-application) tutorial

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Flip() method. Just ensure that the frame is not corrupted or null before calling it!

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.0.0.0/html/304d1f22-93fd-d920-1f4a-285c14594050.htm